# Displaying two images at once

Tags: python-imaging-library, fedora

I have the following simple code (minimum reproducible example):

```py
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("106.jpeg")
img.show()
img = Image.open("108.jpeg")
img.show()
```

The first image is displayed by Image Viewer (Fedora), but the second is not, and Image Viewer gives me the error `No images found in "file:///tmp/tmpegobdyno.PNG".`

However, if I make the program wait with an `input()` statement, and then close the first image before the second one is displayed, there is no error.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use multi threading

Comment: @Darth-CodeX, I don't have experience with threads and that sounds like overkill

Comment: It is not overkill

Comment: On my Fedora system, I have different behavior.  Using your code, but obviously my images, there are no errors.  The second `img.show()` closes the first and then opens the second.  Currently I'm using Gnome on X11.  What are you using?

Comment: GNOME 40.8 on Fedora 34 Workstation Edition. Is that specific enough?